# Using Ember.Select bound to an ArrayController that has an itemController

Tags: ember.js

I have an **Ember.Select** view that has a contentBinding to an ArrayController.  When I set an itemController on the ArrayController, it suddenly throws this error:
**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'child' of null**

Here is a minimalist example:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
    {{view Ember.Select viewName="select"
                    contentBinding="App.monstersController"
                    optionLabelPath="content.name"
                    optionValuePath="content.id"
                    prompt="Pick a monster:"
                    selectionBinding="App.stateController.selectedMonster"}}

</script>
```

And the javascript:

```
window.App = Em.Application.create();

App.ApplicationController = Em.Controller.extend({});

App.ApplicationView = Em.View.extend({
    templateName: 'application'
});

App.data = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "Grog",
    strength: 10,
    species: "Troll"
}, {
    id: 2,
    name: "Ognog",
    strength: 8,
    species: "Goblin"
}, {
    id: 3,
    name: "Fred",
    strength: 3,
    species: "Human"
}];

App.stateController = Em.Controller.create({
    selectedMonster: null
});

App.MonsterController = Em.ObjectController.extend({
    name: function() {
        return "Controller Modified " + this.get('name');
    }.property('content.name')
});

App.MonstersController = Em.ArrayController.extend({
    content: App.data/*,
    itemController: "monster"*/
});

App.monstersController = App.MonstersController.create({});
```

Here is a fiddle, demonstrating the problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/Malkyne/AkHhF/

Does anyone have any idea what is going on here, or how I can fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much fiddling (ha!), I think I have a working solution.  Here were the steps:

1.) Add an **ApplicationRoute** specification to set up the controller.  That looks like this:

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function() {
    this.controllerFor('monsters').set('content', App.data);
  }
});
```

2.) Remove the **content** element out of **App.MonstersController**, because that content is now being assigned in the Router.  Now, it looks like this:

```
App.MonstersController = Em.ArrayController.extend({
    itemController: 'monster'
});
```

3.) Pull the Ember.Select view out of the template entirely, because even if I call that view "monsters," I can't seem to figure out a way to get it to bind its content to the monsters collection.  Replace it with this:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">    
    {{render monsters}}
</script>
```

4.) Now, let's extend Ember.Select to make our new view:

```
App.MonstersView = Ember.Select.extend({
    contentBinding: 'this.controller',
    prompt: "Pick a monster:",
    selectionBinding: 'App.stateController.selectedMonster',
    optionLabelPath: 'content.name',
    optionValuePath: 'content.id'
});
```

Here is a working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Malkyne/KGJXE/

So, the moral of this story is that in the *recent* versions of Ember, dangling controllers out in the App namespace don't seem to behave very well.  If you initialize controllers in your Route **setupController** function, they seem to behave much better.